# Pathlib absolute path name with brackets

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have the following `file`:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Python\[dtag] filename [another tag].mp4
```

Normally for every file, I'll use `Path(file).name` to get the filename with extension, which in this case **should** result in

```
[dtag] filename [another tag].mp4
```

However, it seems that the the brackets at the beginning of the filename are causing issues, resulting in:

```
 filename [another tag].mp4
```

So it removed the `[dtag]` part from the filename. Similar goes for doing `Path(file).as_posix()` and `Path(file).parts[-1]`, `os.path.basename(file)` and many other methods.

I simply do not want to alter the original filename, and I want to keep using the Pathlib module, but I can't think of a way to make this work.

Comment: is file expressed as a string?  If it is could you express it as a row string (i.e. r."filename".  I don't know if that helps or not, but worth a try.

Comment: It's assigned as a variable, `file`. I've tried using several things, including `r"{}".format(file)`, but that doesn't neem to do it either.

Comment: I know it is the variable file, what I was asking is what is the type of variable 'File'

Comment: Excuse me for misunderstanding, well `file` is indeed a string indeed like you initially thought.

Comment: Okay, I just an experiment on my system Win 10 running Python 8.5, I created several files on my hard drive that included the [tag] data as well as the same file without the [tag] data in the names.  I then tested if these files were detected by both patrhlib.Path and os..path_exists methods.  All files were found and determined to be valid files.  Not sure if this helps you, but could be an indication, your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: BTW: I originally had a problem when my file names on the hard drive were not exactly as I had anticipated, so look carefully at the file name to ensure there isn't an extra character or something weird.

Comment: @itprorh66 - are you sure you're running Python `8.5`?  I thought the current version is `3.9`?

Comment: Yes, I originally ran the tests with Python 3.8.5.  I have also run the tests with Python 3.8.6 and 3.9.1 with same results.